# Variable changing when used in a forumula in php

Tags: php

I hope that someone can help me figure this out because it is driving me crazy. First off some background and values of the variables below.

The `$TritPrice` variable fluctuates as it comes from another source but for an example, lets say that the value of it is `5.25`

$RefineTrit is constant at `1000` and `$Minerals[$oretype][0]` is `333`

When I first goto the page where this code is, and this function runs for some reason the `$TritPrice` var either get truncated to `5.00` or gets rounded down but only during the formula itself. I can echo each of variables and they are correct but when I echo the formula and do the math manually the `$TritPrice` is just `5` instead of `5.25`.

If I put in `$TritPrice = 5.25;` before the if statement it works fine and after the form is submitted and this function is rerun it works fine.

The page that uses this function is at [here](http://www.k5aec.net/eve/ore.php) if yall want to see what it does.

```
If ($Minerals[$oretype][1] <> 0) {
    $RefineTrit = getmintotal($oretype,1);
    if ($RefineTrit < $Minerals[$oretype][1]) {
       $NonPerfectTrit = $Minerals[$oretype][1] + 
                            ($Minerals[$oretype][1] - $RefineTrit);
       $Price = (($TritPrice * $NonPerfectTrit) / $Minerals[$oretype][0]);
    } else { 
       $Price = $TritPrice * $RefineTrit / $Minerals[$oretype][0];
    }
}
```

This is where the $TritPrice

```
// Get Mineral Prices
GetCurrentMineralPrice();
$TritPrice = $ItemPrice[1];
$PyerPrice = $ItemPrice[2];
$MexPrice = $ItemPrice[3];
$IsoPrice = $ItemPrice[4];
$NocxPrice = $ItemPrice[5];
$ZydPrice = $ItemPrice[6];
$MegaPrice = $ItemPrice[7];
$MorPrice = $ItemPrice[8];
```

and the GetCurrentMineralPrice() function is

```
function GetCurrentMineralPrice() {

global $ItemPrice;

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=39&typeid=40&typeid=11399&usesystem=30000142");
$i = 1;

foreach ($xml->marketstat->type as $child) {

    $ItemPrice[$i] = $child->buy->max;
    $i++;

}

return $ItemPrice;
```

}

Comment: Ohhh an Eve Online issue! What is in this function `getmintotal()`?

Comment: That gets how much of a mineral is refined from an ore...ie 1000 trit from 333 veldspar...just assigns the var from an array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in this piece of code. In some other part of the program, and I suspect it is the place where the values from the textboxes are accepted and fed into the formula - in that place there should be a function or code snippet that is rounding the value of $TritPrice. Check the place where the $_POST values are being fetched and also check if any javascript code is doing a parseInt behind the scenes.

Comment: if you goto the website listed, I am echoing the individual vars and the formula...basically added echo $TritPrice . " * " . $RefineTrit . " / " . $Minerals[$oretype][0] . " = " . $TritPrice * $RefineTrit / $Minerals[$oretype][0] . "<br>"; before the last } and it still is just taking 5 instead of 5.18 or whatever the current price is...

Answer (score 0):

EVE-Online ftw.

with that out of the way, it's possible that your precision value in your config is set too low? Not sure why it would be unless you changed it manually. Or you have a function that is running somewhere that is truncating your variable when you call it from that function/var

However, can you please paste the rest of the code where you instantiate $TritPrice please?